# Using BeautifulSoup to extract current version of Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, version, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the Firefox download page for the current US English version of Firefox for download using Python and BeautifulSoup. I am using Python version 2.4.3.

I believe that I am close, but could use some pointers to guide me in the right direction.

Here is my current code:

```
    import urllib2
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

    url = "http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/";

    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    #version = soup.find('tr', {'id': 'en-US'}).find('td', {'class': 'download         win'}.find('a', {'product': 'firefox'})
    version = soup.find('tr', {'id': 'en-US'}).find('td', {'class': 'download win'})
    print version # Put a mail command here
```

The uncommented line outputs the following:

```
    <td class="download win"><a href="https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox- 23.0.1&amp;os=win&amp;lang=en-US" title="Download for Windows">Download</a></td>
```

The commented line outputs an error:

```
    File "firefox-version.py", line 11
        print version # Put a mail command here
            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I suspect that the data that I am retrieving cannot be stored the way I am instructing Python to handle the results that are returned. I started looking at using find_all instead of just find, but I am not sure if that is taking me in the right direction. Any clues would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You're getting a syntax error. This kind of error is completely unrelated to the logic of your code, it just means your code is not valid Python. Run `import sys; sys.version` to check which version of python you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The `print version` syntax works fine in Python 2.4, it shouldn't generate a syntax error. Verify that that's *really* the version in use, because in Python 3.x `print version` *will* cause a syntax error. Just to be sure, check if this works: `print(version)`.